# Setting background for user control in mainwindow not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I've created a user control called "TestUserControl"

Inside my Mainwindow.xaml file I called my TestUserControl as follows:

```
<controls:TestUserControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext}" Background="Blue" />
```

The problem is the blue background isn't being reflected in the actual user control. Is there something I have to do in TestUserControl.xaml to let it accept the data when called from Mainwindow.xaml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We know nothing about your user control. Is it being affected by a control template? If so, does that control template have any template bindings to the background property? [This is what happens when I use your exact code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cweM8.png). Supply more info.

Comment: It should  , i'm guessing something inside your UserControl is hiding the background . 

could you post your UserControl's xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

A User Control as it is definition has no representation of it is properties, it is only visually represented with it is controls inside like panels and more controls. Then you can for instance do the following:

```
<controls:TestUserControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext}" x:Name="Instance">
 <Grid Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=Instance}"/>
<controls:TestUserControl/>
```

And Apply all the base properties of a Control as you consider depending how you represent the control.

Comment: This is wrong. Setting a `UserControl`'s `Background` property will affect the appearance of the control just like any other. See my comment.

Comment: Might be in WPF but due to is not showing I understand that is not using WPF